# Field not setting properly in GEE Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, mean, reduceregion

I'm currently using the GEE Python API to calculate multiple fields (an example is soil moisture) for multiple features representing forest fires. While uploading the dataset, I first filter it to the bounds of **table**, a custom geometry I have imported. I then run filters to remove bad geometries (which are present in the GlobFire dataset), and filter by other fields like initial date and area.

```
dataset = ee.FeatureCollection('JRC/GWIS/GlobFire/v2/FinalPerimeters').filterBounds(table).filter(ee.Filter.gte('IDate', 1483228800000)).filter(ee.Filter.intersects(".geo", ee.Geometry.Point(0,0)).Not()).filter(ee.Filter.area(60000, 3000000000))
```

I then get the coordinates of the centroid of each feature and add the latitude and longitude as fields, as well as the month and day of the initial date of each forest fire. These fields are set appropriately and I face no issues with them.

However, when I try to add fields like soil moisture, as seen in the code below:

```
def get_sm(feature):
    start = ee.Number(feature.get('IDate')).subtract(604800000);
    end = ee.Number(feature.get('IDate'))
    sm = soilmoisture.filterDate(start, end).filterBounds(feature.geometry()).select('soil_moisture_am').mean().clip(feature.geometry())
    sm2 = sm.reproject(crs = 'SR-ORG:6974', scale = 11132)
    reduced_sm = sm2.reduceRegion(reducer = ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry = feature.geometry(), scale = 11132, maxPixels = 1e9)
    return feature.set('soil_moisture', reduced_sm.get('soil_moisture_am'))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda feature: get_sm(feature))
dataset.first()
```

The field **'soil_moisture'** is not set/visible when printing `dataset.first()`. Some background here: I first find the mean image of the soil moisture, then reproject it from EPSG:4326 to SR-ORG:6974. I then run `ee.reduceRegion()` to find the mean soil moisture for the whole region.

Why isn't **soil_moisture** setting?

Comment: to be able to give a proper answer the code must be reproducible, but at first glance the issue could be that the property value is `null` and instead of showing as it is it shows that the property does not exist. I have had this issue before and you could even catch it using `ee.Algorithms.If`